# Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash when solana program deploy

Tags: blockchain, solana

Trying to deploy a program to solana devnet.

I was using
`solana program deploy ./path/xxxx.so -u devnet`

And I got multiple lines of

```
msg 21AbKBwMcsDR4DciR6Z69X6vrqVj7uHKg2Wf1ap8FB1J
msg 21AbKBwMcsDR4DciR6Z69X6vrqVj7uHKg2Wf1ap8FB1J
msg 21AbKBwMcsDR4DciR6Z69X6vrqVj7uHKg2Wf1ap8FB1J
msg 21AbKBwMcsDR4DciR6Z69X6vrqVj7uHKg2Wf1ap8FB1J
msg 21AbKBwMcsDR4DciR6Z69X6vrqVj7uHKg2Wf1ap8FB1J
```

It gave me this error in the end

```
Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash
```

Tried search online but didn't get any useful informations

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this error by reverting to earlier versions of solana-cli and anchor-cli

```
solana-cli 1.8.0 (src:4a8ff62a; feat:1813598585)
anchor-cli 0.18.2
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

I also shared the above solution in this related [github issue](https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/issues/1157)

One guess I have is that `ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256))` (which was in my error logs) could be a "time out error" from waiting too long due to slower deployment validation.

I did notice my deployments using later versions (solana-cli 1.9.1, anchor-cli 0.20.1) being significantly slower, especially for larger programs (my small program deployments were still working fine). These were the versions that showed similar "msg" logging as OP.

UPDATE:

Nowadays, my most fool proof solution is to run the snippet below before deployments

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.8.13/install)"
```

Answer (score 3):

For deploying to devnet via Anchor, the error I got:

```
Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

I have solved this:

```
Local npm package: @project-serum/anchor 0.20.1
Solana program dependencies: anchor-lang 0.20.1, anchor-spl 0.20.1, solana-program 1.9.4
deploy to devnet: failed

Local npm package: @project-serum/anchor 0.19.0
Solana program dependencies: anchor-lang 0.19.0, anchor-spl 0.19.0, solana-program 1.9.4
deploy to devnet: successful or failed

Local npm package: @project-serum/anchor 0.18.2
Solana program dependencies: anchor-lang 0.18.2, anchor-spl 0.18.2, solana-program 1.9.4
deploy to devnet: successful or failed
```

in all cases, the global environment is the same:

```
Rust 1.57.0
solana-cli 1.9.4
@project-serum/anchor-cli 0.20.1
```

it seems sometimes the transaction may fail and those transactions include program deployment. see reference: https://www.brianfriel.xyz/resending-dropped-transactions-on-solana/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be only because of anchor's version, I had the following versions installed:

```
Rust 1.59.0
solana-cli 1.9.6
anchor-lang 0.22.1
```

I couldn't deploy to devnet because of

```
Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

So I just changed `anchor-lang` to `0.22.0` and all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange, and not the normal output that you should get while deploying a program.  Have you tried updating to the latest Solana SDK, which is 1.9.2 at the time of writing? More docs at https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#use-solanas-install-tool

I just tried this on devnet, and got the following output:

```
$ solana program deploy path/to/program.so -u devnet
Finding leader nodes...
[x/y] Transactions sent...
[x/y] Transactions confirmed. Retrying in z blocks.
Program Id: 6sxk3XpYapcRnpSwRKFS1nGK9MJpm8Jkb9aofnBcG1p8
```

Comment: Interesting, yes I think I'm using the latest solana sdk, I'm just following the testing sections of metaplex https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex#testing , there is a step to deploy the program to devnet

Answer (score 0):

For Mac M1,

```
Rust 1.57.0
solana-cli 1.8.0
@project-serum/anchor-cli 0.20.1
```

these tools' versions work.
I tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/issues/1157#issuecomment-1065828414
try solana cli 1.8.12 as 1.9.* seems to have issues deploying on devnet

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error in chainlink contract [github example](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/solana-starter-kit/blob/main/programs/chainlink_solana_demo/src/lib.rs). I changed this line  in Execute Struct

```
pub system_program:Program<'info,System>,
```

to this:

```
#[account(address=system_program::ID)]
/// CHECK:
pub system_program:AccountInfo<'info>,
```

I had to import `system_program`

```
use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_program;
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, to solve it my solana-cli version was 1.9.4 and I just updated with

```
solana-install update
```

and it's downgraded to 1.8.16 and deployed my program without any problem.
before this I can't deploy using anchor test(process) or solana program deploy.

Also, If you upgrade to one of the 1.10.X versions the issue will fix.